# Java - Arranging irregular shapes

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I am trying to develop an Java code in which regular/irregular shapes will be arranged in that manner so that I can utilize whole page consider. I want make an application which will try to find all possible way to arrange the custom shapes into given area, so that I can utilize my area as much possible. I have read the to generating probability using [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class. Also I've made small snippet I know its not working as I stated but I want to arrange these shape. Any algorithm or link would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
public class DrawGraph {

    JPanel panel;
    JFrame frame;
    Random rand;
    public DrawGraph()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Graph");
        rand = new Random();
        panel = new JPanel(){

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g2)
            {
                super.paintComponents(g2);
                Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g2;
                g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                int i,j,x=0,y=0;
                int width = panel.getWidth();
                int height = panel.getHeight();
                int intervalX = (int)Math.round(width*0.02);
                int intervalY = (int)Math.round(height*0.02);
                for(i=0,j=0;i<=width || j<=height;i+=intervalX,j+=intervalY)
                {
                    g.drawLine(x, j, width, j);
                    g.drawLine(i,y,i,height);
                }
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
                    generateShape(g);
            }
        };
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void generateShape(Graphics2D g)
    {
        //demo shape
        int radius = rand.nextInt(200);
        int originX,originY;
        originX = rand.nextInt(300-10) + 10;
        originY = rand.nextInt(300-10) + 10;
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
        g.drawOval(originX, originY, radius, radius);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         new DrawGraph();
    }

}
```

Here the output:
I want to use the remaining space as much as I can.
[image]

Comment: This sounds like an NP-HARD or NP-COMPLETE problem.

Comment: @Kayaman I didn't get you what are you trying to say?

Comment: What he was trying to say is 'try to find all possible way to arrange the custom shapes into given area' is something that cannot be solved by writing a computer program or at least solvable in a fixed time.There are simply too many possibilities to think of and there is no fixed condition on which the program can terminate.

Comment: But can't my case match with the drag and drop functionality provided in IDE's?

Comment: Think of this.You know how to re-arrange stuff so that it occupies the screen well,how to feed this to a computer,can you come up with a criteria or a condition?

Comment: See also [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).